# C - Using fgets until newline/-1

Tags: c, while-loop, stdin

So I'm trying to make it so that you can write text into a file until you make a newline or type -1. My problem is that when you write, it just keeps going until it crashes and gives the error ***"Stack around the variable "inputChoice" was corrupted"***.

I believe the problem is that the program doesn't stop accepting **stdin** when you want to stop typing (-1, newline) and that causes the error. I've tried with a simple scanf and it works, but you can only write a word. No spaces and it doesn't support multiple lines either. That's why I have to use **fgets**

Comment: `while (input != "-1\n")` you are comparing pointers, not the contents. To compare the contents of strings, use [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: I tried that as well but it doesn't change anything. I still get the same error

Comment: `input` is unitialized,, the first `strcmp` is undefined behavior

Comment: Just because it's not causing the symptom you're seeing, didn't mean it's wrong.  You should definitely be using strcmp, regardless of what else is wrong.

Comment: Your first call of `strcmp` has an undefined behaviour, because `input` is uninitialised and `strcmp` expects a C-String. Do `char input[LOAD] = { 0 }; ` so that input has an empty string.

Comment: A second big problem is that `inputChoice` is only a `char`, you cannot do  `scanf("%s", &inputChoice);` Here `scanf` expects a pointer to a field of chars, thus `scanf`is writing in places that it isn't allowed to do (this is an overflow).

Comment: I'm not getting this anyway.. you're looping until the user enters -1, but you're not saving the input anywhere, so you're just going to loop and throw away your data through each loop until -1 is entered, at which point -1 is the only data you have? Also is `LOAD` == 1024?

Comment: How would I go about saving the input? I'm very new to C so forgive me if I'm asking stupid questions

Comment: A third problem is the whole question about saving. What's the purpose of this question? I think you should rethink the whole program and writing down in a piece of paper what you want to do and what you expect the interface to ask you. This might help you organize your thoughts.

Comment: no not a stupid question,, just each time through your `while` loop you're going to overwrite what's in `input`.. you'll need to save that off to some other buffer each time if you want to retain that data for later.

Comment: @Cryptosyche *How would I go about saving the input?* in that case, you still don't have sufficient knowledge to do this. Take a piece of paper and a pencil and try to solve your problem with these two tools, draw a picture or something that illustrates your thoughts. That helps seeing the big picture.

Comment: Note that you must check the return value from `fgets()` itself; it will tell you if you reach EOF by returning a null pointer.  As it stands, you'll never be able to detect EOF.

Comment: I appreciate you all for the comments, but the main question was why the program crashes (inputChoice  was corrupted), not how to fix all flaws in the program. Even though it makes the code look better and function better, it still gives the same error even after I fixed everything that you commented. @Pablo

Comment: @Cryptosyche Can you post an updated version of your code?

Comment: @Pablo I haven't changed much, got very demotivated after trying for a while. I changed the %s to an %c at scanf(" %c, &inputChoice) and that seems to have stopped the program from crashing. Now I just need to make it so that after user types in -1, the fgets will stop. Also need to add so that fgets actually saves the sdin.

Comment: Why are you using both LOAD and 1024?

Comment: @EdHeal I forgot to remove LOAD. But LOAD = 1024

Comment: @Cryptosyche ok, I'm gonna write you an answer addressing some of things you don't seem to know/understand. Right now I'm busy, so I'll do it in the next couple of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your comments, I assume that there are some basic concepts in C
that you haven't fully understood, yet.

**C-Strings**

A C-String is a sequence of bytes. This sequence **must** end with the value 0.
Every value in the sequence represents a character based on the
[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding, for example the
character `'a'` is 97, `'b'` is 98, etc. The character `'\0'` has
the value 0 and it's the character that determines the end of the string.
That's why you hear a lot that C-Strings are '\0'-terminated.

In C you use an array of chars (`char string[]`, `char string[SOME VALUE]`) to
save a string. For a string of length *n*, you need an array of dimension *n+1*, because
you also need one space for the terminating `'\0'` character.

When dealing with strings, you always have to think about the proper type,
whether your are using an array or a pointer. A pointer
to char doesn't necessarily mean that you are dealing with a C-String!

Why am I telling you this? Because of:

```
char inputChoice = 0;

printf("Do you wish to save the Input? (Y/N)\n");
scanf("%s", &inputChoice);
```

> I haven't changed much, got very demotivated after trying for a while.
>   I changed the `%s` to an `%c` at `scanf(" %c, &inputChoice)` and that
>   seems to have stopped the program from crashing.

which shows that haven't understood the difference between `%s` and `%c`.

The `%c` conversion specifier character tells `scanf` that it must match a single character and it expects a pointer to `char`.

*man scanf*

> c
>
> Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the maximum field
>   width (default 1); **the next pointer  must  be  a
>   pointer  to  char,  and there must be enough room for all the characters
>   (no terminating null byte is added).**  The usual skip of
>   leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.

Forget the bit about the length, it's not important right now. 
The important part is in bold. For the format `scanf("%c"`, the function
expects a pointer to `char` and its not going to write the terminating `'\0'`
character, it won't be a C-String. If you want to read one letter and one
letter only:

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);

// also possible, but only the first char
// will have a defined value
char c[10];
scanf("%c", c);
```

The first one is easy to understand. The second one is more interesting: Here
you have an array of `char` of dimension 10 (i.e it holds 10 `char`s). `scanf`
will match a single letter and write it on `c[0]`. However the result won't be
a C-String, you cannot pass it to `puts` nor to other functions that expect
C-Strings (like `strcpy`).

The `%s` conversion specifier character tells `scanf` that it must match a sequence of non-white-space characters

*man scanf*

> s
>   Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; **the next pointer must be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a character array that  is  long  enough to
>   hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), which is added
>   automatically.**

Here the result will be that a C-String is saved. You also have to have enough
space to save the string:

```
char string[10];
scanf("%s", string);
```

If the strings matches 9 or less characters, everything will be fine, because
for a string of length 9 requires 10 spaces (never forget the terminating
`'\0'`). If the string matches more than 9 characters, you won't have enough
space in the buffer and a buffer overflow (accessing beyond the size) occurs.
This is an undefined behaviour and anything can happen: your program might
crash, your program might not crash but overwrites another variable and thus
scrwes the flow of your program, it could even kill a kitten somewhere, do
you really want to kill kittens?

So, do you see why your code is wrong?

```
char inputChoice = 0;
scanf("%s", &inputChoice);
```

`inputChoice` is a `char` variable, it can only hold **1** value.
`&inputChoice` gives you the address of the `inputChoice` variable, but the
char after that is out of bound, if you read/write it, you will have an
overflow, thus you kill a kitten. Even if you enter only 1 character, it will
write at least 2 bytes and because you it only has space for one character, a kitten will die.

---

So, let's talk about your code.

From the perspective of an user: Why would I want to enter lines of text, possibly a lot of lines of text
and then answer "No, I don't want to save the lines". It doesn't make sense to
me.

In my opinion you should first ask the user whether he/she wants to save the
input first, and **then** ask for the input. If the user doesn't want to save
anything, then there is no point in asking the user to enter anything at
all. But that's just my opinion.

If you really want to stick to your plan, then you have to save every line and
when the user ends entering data, you ask and you save the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERLEN 1024


void printFile () {
    int i;
    char openFile[BUFFERLEN];
    FILE *file;

    printf("What file do you wish to write in?\n");
    scanf("%s", openFile);
    getchar();

    file = fopen(openFile, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return;
    }

    // we save here all lines to be saved
    char **lines = NULL;
    int num_of_lines = 0;

    char buffer[BUFFERLEN];
    printf("Enter an empty line of -1 to end input\n");

    // for simplicity, we assume that no line will be
    // larger than BUFFERLEN - 1 chars
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
    {
        // we should check if the last character is \n,
        // if not, buffer was not large enough for the line
        // or the stream closed. For simplicity, I will ignore
        // these cases
        int len = strlen(buffer);
        if(buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
            buffer[len - 1] = '\0';


        if(strcmp(buffer, "") == 0 || strcmp(buffer, "-1") == 0)
            break; // either an empty line or user entered "-1"

        char *line = strdup(buffer);

        if(line == NULL)
            break; // if no more memory
                   // process all lines that already have been entered


        char **tmp = realloc(lines, (num_of_lines+1) * sizeof *tmp);

        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            free(line);
            break; // same reason as for strdup failing
        }

        lines = tmp;

        lines[num_of_lines++] = line;  // save the line and increase num_of_lines
    }

    char inputChoice = 0;

    printf("Do you wish to save the Input? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%c", &inputChoice);
    getchar();

    if (inputChoice == 'Y' || inputChoice == 'y') {

        for(i = 0; i < num_of_lines; ++i)
            fprintf(file, "%s\n", lines[i]); // writing every line

        printf("Your file has been saved\n");
        printf("Please press any key to continue");
        getchar();
    }

    // closing FILE buffer
    fclose(file);

    // free memory
    if(num_of_lines)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < num_of_lines; ++i)
            free(lines[i]);
        free(lines);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    printFile();
    return 0;
}
```

**Remarks on the code**

I used the same code as yours as the base for mine, so that you can spot the
differences much quicker.

- I use the macro `BUFFERLEN` for declaring the length of the buffers. That's
  my style.
- Look at the `fgets` line:

  ```
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)
  ```

  I use here `sizeof buffer` instead of 1024 or `BUFFERLEN`. Again, that's my
  style, but I think doing this is better, because even if you change the size
  of the buffer by changing the macro, or by using another explicit size, `sizeof buffer`
  will always return the correct size. Be aware that this only works when
  `buffer` is an array.
- The function `strdup` returns a pointer a pointer to a new string that
  duplicates the argument. It's used to create a new copy of a string. When
  using this function, don't forget that you have to free the memory using
  `free()`. `strdup` is not part of the standard library, it conforms
  to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001. If you use Windows (I don't use Windows,
  I'm not familiar with the Windows ecosystem), this function might not be
  present. In that case you can write your own:

  ```
  char *strdup(const char *s)
  {
      char *str = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
      if(str == NULL)
          return NULL;
      strcpy(str, s);
      return str;
  }
  ```

Comment: Nit, `%c` *"type modifier"* should be *"conversion specification"* (or as normally referred to *"conversion specifier"*). A *"type modifier"* refers to, e.g. `'l'` as in `"%lf"` to denote a `double`. Also it would be nice to introduce the use of the *maximum field width*, e.g. `scanf ("%9s", string);` to protect the array bounds in your example. The answer shows very good effort and the man page citations are nice.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the feedback. I'm guilty of not having read the man page with 100% accuracy, hence using the wrong terms. I fixed that in my answer. *Also it would be nice to introduce the use of the maximum field width* yes I thought of that as well, but I wanted to keep as simple as possible without getting into to much detail, since I believe that the OP is rather a beginner and this would have confused more than helped. I think for documentation's sake I'll do an edit about this later.

Comment: No worries. Answer showed great effort, but I only get one vote, and it was already given. Good job.

Comment: Thank you for the long and descriptive explanation. Not only does it assist me with the task at hand but also helps me understand a bigger part of C. Once again, thank for the help and for saving the kittens.

Comment: @Cryptosyche that's ok, when I was a beginner, I made these kind of mistakes all the time, every time I needed a string, my first try ended up with a segfault. Understanding C-Strings, the difference between array and pointers and how to handle them is key. It takes a while, but if you keep practising, you'll get it someday, too.

Comment: Upvoted for the effort, but I think this question is incomplete and lacks MCVE and hence should not be answered. That is what I feel.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya thanks, but when I wrote this, the question did have code, the OP removed it 2 days later (judging from the edit logs). I don't understand why, but I've seen a few times that people remove the code from the question after a few days.

Comment: @Pablo wow that's something new. Maybe because it is an assignment and OP wants to avoid plagiarism issues.